# Netcat UDP server is not sending a response

Tags: linux, udp, netcat

I'm trying to get OpenBSD netcat to listen to UDP connections on a particular port (3333) and interface (10.42.0.1) and send a fixed response. To achieve this I do:

```
echo "asd" | nc -k -u -l -p 3333 -s 10.42.0.1 -v
```

And then I send a message by doing:

```
echo qwe | nc -u 10.42.0.1 3333 -v
```

The outputs are

```
# Server side
Bound on h9ct3d3 3333
XXXXXqwe

# Client side
Connection to 10.42.0.1 3333 port [udp/*] succeeded!
```

As you can see, the client does not receive `asd`. However, if I remove the `-k`, it does receive it:

```
##### Server side
echo "asd" | nc -u -l -p 3333 -s 10.42.0.1 -v
Bound on h9ct3d3 3333
# ...
# Wait for the client to execute
# ...
Connection received on h9ct3d3 51318
XXXXXqwe

##### Client side
echo qwe | nc -u 10.42.0.1 3333 -v
# ...
# Wait for the above 'X'to finish
# ...
Connection to 10.42.0.1 3333 port [udp/*] succeeded!
asd
```

I have tried to use a while loop without the `-k`, but `nc` never returns:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    echo "Host message" | nc -q 0 -u -l -p 3333 -s 10.42.0.1 -v
    echo "restarting..."
done
```

**How can I make this work?**

My version of netcat is:

```
OpenBSD netcat (Debian patchlevel 1.206-1ubuntu1)
```

PD. Why does the `nc` server 'send' those weird `X` characters? The client never reads them, it just waits for them to finish. They seem to be displayed every 1 sec.

Answer (score 1):

The server isn't sending the Xs; the client is sending them, at intervals of 1 second after the first two, and the server *displays* them (as it should). If you take `-v` off the *client*, the Xs aren't sent, or displayed, and the data is sent and displayed immediately (not after 3sec). I have no clue *why* `-v` means 'send 5 X characters slowly'!

The man page for `-k` says

> When used together with the -u option, the server socket is
> not connected and it can receive UDP datagrams from multiple
> hosts.

Consistent with this, server `-v` logs `Connection from {host} {port} received!` when using `-ul` but not when using `-ulk`.
I *suspect* the code for sending the 'response' data relies on the socket being connected, and thus leaving it not connected prevents the response, but I have not dug through the source to verify.

`-q 0` isn't going to work because there is no detectable 'end of connection' in UDP, while there is in TCP (FIN exchange). If there is something recognizable about your client data -- such as `head -1` if it is, always, one line -- logically it should be possible to write something that recognizes that data and kills the `nc` process allowing the loop to iterate, but I haven't been able to work out a clean way to get the pid of the `nc` available to such a recognizer/killer. Making CW in case anyone else can provide a real solution here.